# Can't assign Roles to Users

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm making an ASP.NET MVC5 application with Individual user authentication. I can create users and I've added roles by manually going to dbo.AspNetRoles and typing them in. What I want to do is add the user to dbo.AspNetUserRoles (which has UserId and RolesId as columns) programmatically. I'm trying to work with as little custom classes and such as possible, just changing the default stuff. I don't know how to assign the roles to users.

Answer (score 0):

please read this article completely :
https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/ASPNET-MVC-5-Security-And-44cbdb97

Adding roles programmatically (add this method to your startup.cs) :

```
 private void createRolesandUsers()   
    {   
        ApplicationDbContext context = new ApplicationDbContext();   

        var roleManager = new RoleManager<IdentityRole>(new RoleStore<IdentityRole>(context));   
        var UserManager = new UserManager<ApplicationUser>(new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(context));   


        // In Startup iam creating first Admin Role and creating a default Admin User    
        if (!roleManager.RoleExists("Admin"))   
        {   

            // first we create Admin rool   
            var role = new Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework.IdentityRole();   
            role.Name = "Admin";   
            roleManager.Create(role);   

            //Here we create a Admin super user who will maintain the website                  

            var user = new ApplicationUser();   
            user.UserName = "shanu";   
            user.Email = "syedshanumcain@gmail.com";   

            string userPWD = "A@Z200711";   

            var chkUser = UserManager.Create(user, userPWD);   

            //Add default User to Role Admin   
            if (chkUser.Succeeded)   
            {   
                var result1 = UserManager.AddToRole(user.Id, "Admin");   

            }   
        }   

        // creating Creating Manager role    
        if (!roleManager.RoleExists("Manager"))   
        {   
            var role = new Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework.IdentityRole();   
            role.Name = "Manager";   
            roleManager.Create(role);   

        }   

        // creating Creating Employee role    
        if (!roleManager.RoleExists("Employee"))   
        {   
            var role = new Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework.IdentityRole();   
            role.Name = "Employee";   
            roleManager.Create(role);   

        }   
    }
```

defining user role after registeration :

```
  await this.UserManager.AddToRoleAsync(user.Id, model.UserRoles);
```